# Вызов модального окна с частичным представлением Asp Mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Есть представление такого вида

```
<div class="ui three stackable cards">
    @foreach (var s in Model.Suppliers)
    {
        <div class="ui card link">
            <div class="content">
                <div id ="go" style="display:none" >@s.SupplierID</div>
                <h2 class="header">@s.ShortName</h2>
                <div class="meta" style="font-size: 0.92857143rem; ">
                    <span style="color:black">@s.Name</span><br />
                    <span>ИНН: @s.Inn</span>
                </div>
                <div style="font-weight:700; font-size: 0.92857143rem; margin-top:1em;">
                    @foreach (var ph in s.Phones)
                    {
                        <i class="phone icon"></i> @ph.PhoneNumber<br />
                    }
                    @foreach (var em in s.Emails)
                    {
                        <a href="mailto:@em.Contact_Email" target="_top"><i class="mail icon"></i>@em.Contact_Email</a><br />

                    }
                    <a href="http://@s.Site" target="_blank"><i class="world icon"></i>@s.Site</a> <br />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Получается вот такое представление

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо, чтобы по клику на карточке появлялось модальное окно с деталями поставщика.

Для этого мне нужно в контроллер передать Id, поэтому в представлении я создал скрытый div с Id постановщика

```
<div id ="go" style="display:none" >@s.SupplierID</div>
```

Затем Get запросом передаю в контроллер Id. Написал вот такую функцию для этих целей.

```
function get(){
            $('.card').click(function () {
                $('.navbar-fixed-top').css("z-index", "1");

                var id = $("#go", this).text();
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("GET", '/Supplier/Details/'+ id, true)
                xhr.send();

            });
        };
```

Все отлично работает. Контроллер выглядит так.

```
   [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Details(int id)

        {
            var supplier = db.Suppliers.Find(id);
            if (supplier == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return PartialView("_Supplier_Details", supplier);

        }
```

Может я не правильно всю схему со скрытыми слоями придумал, может есть и другие простые варианты, буду рад подсказкам.

Но основная проблема в том, как Вы видите выше в контроллере я передаю модель в частичное представление, которое должно быть модальным окном. Как его вызвать я не знаю, у меня тупик. Пока я создал `_Supplier_Details` и туда поместил код модального окна. А дальше? Какие мои шаги?

*Скорее всего нужно дописать в функцию get после окончания запроса вызов этого модального окна, но как мне на него сослаться оно же в отдельном файле в виде частичного представления.*

Comment: Нет semantic ui

Comment: Похоже, у вас не хватает обработки ответа от сервера. Сделайте ajax запрос с помощью `jQuery` и в обработчике `success` вставьте ответ в ваше модальное окно `$('#modal .my-content').html(response)` и вызовите отображение этого окна.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть ещё вот такой способ.
Во вьюхе страницы с поставщиками нужно добавить следующий код:

```
<!-- Для модального окна -->
<div id='myModal' class='modal fade in'>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div id='myModalContent'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/appjs/modal.js")
}
```

Файл modal.js:

```
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $(document).on("click", "a[data-modal]", function (e) {
        $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
            $('#myModal').modal({
                keyboard: true
            }, 'show');

            bindForm(this);
        });
        return false;
    }); 
});

function bindForm(dialog) {
    $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
        $('#progress').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#progress').hide();                      
                    //location.reload();
                } else {
                    $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                    bindForm(this);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}
```

Вьюха деталей:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 class="modal-title">Подробности</h3>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <!-- Содержимое модального окна -->
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Закрыть
    </button>
</div>
```

В моём примере модальное окно открывается при клике по ссылке:

```
<a data-modal='' href='/Album/Details/" + item.AlbumID + "' id='" + item.AlbumID + "' title='Подробности'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'> </span> </a>
```

Вы уж переделаете modal.js под свои нужды :) Надеюсь, что ничего не забыла)