# Как подтянуть через Ajax PartialView во всплывающем окне

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

начал знакомиться с `ASP.NET-MVC-5` и `Ajax`. Задачка в принципе простенькая, но я на ней заткнулся. суть такая: есть некая html страница на которой отрисовывается web-форма, на этой форме присутствует кнопка, по клику которой должно "вываливаться" всплывающее окно, внутри которого некие данные из БД.
Моя проблема в том, что PartialView возвращается мне не как всплывающее окно, а как отдельная вьюха.

HomeController:

```
public ActionResult GetKarmanDetails(string _mnemoName, string _stackName, int? _pocketNum)
{
    new Mapper().LoadDataKarman(_mnemoName, _stackName, Convert.ToInt32(_pocketNum));
    return PartialView("GetKarmanDetails", GlobalCache.GetKarmanDetails);
}
```

Всплывающее окно:

```
@model Mimic_Panel_Sklad3.WebUI.Models.KarmanDetails


<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4>Данные о сортаменте кармана</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <table class="table table-custom">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Диаметр</th>
                <th>Толщина</th>
                <th>Марка стали</th>
                <th>НТД</th>
                <th>Количество труб</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach (var element in Model.Karmans)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@element.DIAMETER</td>
                    <td>@element.THICKNESS</td>
                    <td>@element.STAL</td>
                    <td>@element.GOST</td>
                    <td>@element.COUNT_PIPES</td>
                </tr>
            }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Блок из html-страницы откуда я беру свое окно:(внимание на GetKarmanDetails)

```
 <div class="panel-line">
    <div class="panel-item" style="background-color: @Model.GetStatusKarman(item_karman.COUNT_PIPE_PERCENT)">
        <a href="@Url.Action("GetKarmanDetails", "Home", new {@_stackName = item_karman.STACK_NAME, @_pocketNum = item_karman.POCKET_NUM, @_mnemoName = Model.MNEMO_NAME})">
            <div>
                @foreach (var item_noms in item_karman.Noms)
                {
                    if (item_noms.DIAMETER != null)
                    {
                        <div class="panel-line-nom">
                            <div class="panel-item-nom">@item_noms.DIAMETER</div>
                        </div>
                    }
                    else if (item_noms.DIAMETER == null && item_noms.COUNT_DIAMETER == 0)
                    {
                        <div class="panel-line-nom-empty">
                            <div class="panel-item-nom-empty">@item_noms.DIAMETER</div>
                        </div>
                    }

                }
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

UPD: Я ожидаю, что результатом будет вывод высплывающего окна на той же html-странице, пример:
страница при загрузке:[image: главное представление]
загрузка частичного представления на той же странице:[image: вывод окна поверх основного]

но я получаю ситуацию другую. Мое частичное представление переводит меня на новую страницу, пример:
[image: загрузка страницы]

[image: загрузка частичного представления происходит путём перехода на другую страницу]

Comment: `Моя проблема в том, что PartialView возвращается мне не как всплывающее окно, а как отдельная вьюха.` я как возвращается всплывающее окно?

Comment: @tym32167 т.е. я ожидаю, что мое окно будет показано на той же странице, без перехода

Comment: отображайте его тогда как partialView на той же странице

Comment: @tym32167 так я так и делаю, вызываю его на той же странице  `<a href="@Url.Action("GetKarmanDetails", "Home", new {@_stackName = item_karman.STACK_NAME, @_pocketNum = item_karman.POCKET_NUM, @_mnemoName = Model.MNEMO_NAME})">`

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/14.6.php

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562486/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-asp-mvc

Comment: @4per используйте ваш комментарий как ответ, пожалуйста, материал с метанита указал мне путь движения

Comment: @Sosiska, я слабовато владею темой. А ещё мне кажется, что это дубликат вопроса 562486

Comment: @4per прошу прощения, но это не дубликат, так как суть проблемы разная, мое частичное представления уходило на редирект страницы html, а в том вопросе человек просил как ему вызвать модальное окно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:
    вкратце: решил выводить частичное представление в виде строки, а потом выводить ее на html.

1. Создал новый проджект
2. Добавил 2 новых класса

ControllerExtensions.cs:

```
public static string RenderPartialViewToString(this Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        {
            viewName = controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
        }

        controller.ViewData.Model = model;

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            // Find the partial view by its name and the current controller context.
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);

            // Create a view context.
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);

            // Render the view using the StringWriter object.
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

JSONClass.cs:

```
public class JSONClass : Controller
{
    public class Messages
    {
        public String Success { get; set; }
        public String Info { get; set; }
        public String Error { get; set; }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Флаг пришли ли данные или нет.
    /// </summary>
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Сообщение пользователю
    /// </summary>
    //public String Message { get; set; }
    public Messages Message = new Messages();
    /// <summary>
    /// Вывод сообщения об ошибках(На стороне клиента используется для консольки)
    /// </summary>
    public String ConsoleMessage { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Возвращаемые данные(Обычно это HTML строка, но в разных методах используется по разному)
    /// </summary>
    public String ResultHtml { get; set; }

    public Object Object_j { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Устанавливаем сообщение ошибкию Используется когда срабатывает Exception
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ex"></param>
    public void InstallErrorMessage(Exception ex, string message = null)
    {
        if (message != null)
            Message.Error = message;
        else
            Message.Error = String.Format("Возникла непредвиденная ошибка. По техническим вопросам, связанным с работой сайта, обращаться по телефону: 1111. Направьте свой вопрос в ОМК-ИТ, описав последовательность Ваших действий.");

        ConsoleMessage = String.Format("Message - {0}\r\n\r\n" +
                                                 "InnerException - {1}\r\n\r\n" +
                                                 "StackTrace - {2}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException, ex.StackTrace);
        Success = false;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Метод преобразования данных класса в формат JSON
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Строка в формате JSON</returns>
    public JsonResult ToJson()
    {
        return Json(
            new
            {
                success = Success,
                message = Message,
                consoleMessage = ConsoleMessage,
                resultHtml = ResultHtml,
                object_j = Object_j
            });
    }
}
```

После того, я подкорректировал контроллеры

ControllerInitializer.cs:

```
    public class ControllerInitializer : Controller
{
    public IServiceLayer _serviceLayer { get; set; }
    public JSONClass jsonClass { get; set; }
    public ControllerInitializer(IServiceLayer serviceLayer)
    {
        _serviceLayer = ServiceLayer.Instance(serviceLayer);

        jsonClass = new JSONClass()
        {
            Message = new JSONClass.Messages()
        };
    }
}
```

Ну и соответственно HomeController.cs:

```
public ActionResult GetKarmanDetails(string _mnemoName, string _stackName, int? _pocketNum)
    {
        try
        {
            new Mapper().LoadDataKarman(_mnemoName, _stackName, Convert.ToInt32(_pocketNum));


            jsonClass.ResultHtml = this.RenderPartialViewToString("GetKarmanDetails", GlobalCache.GetKarmanDetails);

            jsonClass.Success = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { jsonClass.InstallErrorMessage(ex); }

        return jsonClass.ToJson();
    }
```

в частичном представлении, откуда мне необходимо было создать модальное окно я иначе стал вызывать мое модальное окно ссылкой:

```
<div class="panel-line-nom" data-plain-mnemo="@Model.MNEMO_NAME"
     data-plain-stack="@item_karman.STACK_NAME"
     data-plain-pocket="@item_karman.POCKET_NUM" >
     @Html.ActionLink(@item_noms.DIAMETER, "GetKarmanDetails", new
     {
        _stackName = item_karman.STACK_NAME,
        _pocketNum = item_karman.POCKET_NUM,
        _mnemoName = Model.MNEMO_NAME
     }, new
     {
        @class = "karmanItem"
     })
</div>
```

И в конечном итоге я добавил обработчик событий, чтобы он мне загружал мое модальное окно:

```
    $("body").on('click', '.karmanItem', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    AJAXGlobals({
        url: href,

        data: {
            _mnemoName: $(this).data('plainMnemo'),
            _stackName: $(this).data('plainStack'),
            _pocketNum: $(this).data('plainPocket')
        },
        success: function (data) {

            $('#dialogContent').html(data.resultHtml);

            $('#modDialog').modal('show');

        }
    });
});
```